# Renaming an XML/SOAP tag using Apache CXF

Tags: soap, cxf

I've got a SOAP web-service server using Apache CXF as implementation. Due to some external technical constraint I'd like to be able to **rename some XML tags** naming an operation parameter (which are deprecated) in the inbound SOAP request. I was reading about using `Interceptors` for this, but the documentation on how to setup/configure them is not very clear.

My code to publish an endpoint is the following:

```
Endpoint endpoint = Endpoint.create(
    "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/", new MyServer());
endpoint.publish("ws/endpoint");
```

Ideally I'd like to add a filter only to a given endpoint (I have several of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache's documentations](https://cxf.apache.org/docs/interceptors.html) about interceptors are quite clear (IMO), anyway, there is a helloworld project (based on spring boot, cxf and maven) in my [github profile](https://github.com/ali4j/ApacheCXFBasicAuthentication) which you can take a look for setting up interceptors (in fact it's a baisc autentication interceptor).

For setting up an interceptor (e.g InInterceptor), your class should extend  `AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message>` and override `handleMessage(Message message)` method, then in the constructor you should declare the `phase` in which the interceptor is going to be applied. Finally you have to instantiate it and apply in on an Endpoint.

As you said:

> rename some XML tags naming an operation parameter (which are
>   deprecated) in the inbound SOAP request

I think the name of the operation parameter (in WSDL file) is something different from the argument of your web method. Suppose that there is method in your endpoint named `addPerson`:

```
@WebMethod
String addPerson(Person person) {
    /*method logic*/
}
```

and Person class:

```
class Person {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Date birthDate;
    //getters and setters
}
```

in order to map `lastName` property to a different name, you have to annotate it with

```
@XmlElement(name = "sureName")
private String lastName;
```

after applying this anotation, `sureName` (in wsdl file) is going to be mapped to `lastName`.

In addition, there is `@WebParam` annotation which can be used for changing the name of web method arguments:

```
@WebMethod
String sayHello( @WebParam(name = "sureName") String lastName);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Second part of your answer is not possible, I would have to rename a method parameter, which I cannot (I need to support v1 and v2 of the API, where the method parameter _name_ has been modified). But thanks for the first part anyway, I guess I need to inspire myself from something like `StaxInInterceptor` or equivalent.

Comment: Changing the name of web method arguments can be done using another annotation, I've updated my answer, please take a look.

Comment: The trick is that I need to support 2 names (old and new one) at the same time. Hence the original question! Otherwise I would have modified the `@WebParam` name for sure :)

Comment: Now I got what you said in your post